# integrating Paypal into a website - is this possible?

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

I'm a bit of a newb and have never integrated paypal into a website before so I apologise for my lack of knowledge.

I'm trying to build a website which allows users to sign up and, assuming they get themselves paypal premier accounts (so they can receive payments by credit card) they will be able to receive payments from other users of my site.

So someone will sign up using their Paypal email address, and other users will then be able to send them money through my site. If they use one of my special services then I also want to be able to take a 1% fee of the money sent.

I'm using cakephp and I've searched and found a few cakephp related paypal components but to me it seems that these are aimed at people who want to just use their own paypal account to receive money. Like having a paypal checkout button. Whereas I want to be able to direct money into many different paypal accounts. Is this possible? And if so can any kind soul direct me to where I should be reading (pref something not too difficult - I'm a learner!).

Also as a side note, are there any special security issues I need to take care of when dealing with paypal, especially considering the particular nature of what I want to achieve? How easy would it be for a bad person to alter someones paypal email to direct funds to themselves?

many thanks in advance
Dave

Comment: Not sure if this is a fitting question for SO. In general, you should consult the PayPal documentation. Anything that is possible with the PayPal API is possible with CakePHP. You just have to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few years ago I did a similar thing, although the specific code is languishing on an old computer somewhere... Anyway, the way I did it was to use a combination of IPN and Paypal Mass Payments. Any payments have to run through your own PP account first and foremost, at which point on a successful payment IPN calls a script to run Mass Payments and send the money to the intended target(s).

It's a bit fiddly, and I seem to remember (at least when I did it) there were some odd bugs in IPN, but this should do it for you.

HOpe this helps a bit!

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for the reply. I'll have to go off and google mass payments and ipn, but I would have thought channelling everything through my own paypal account would have been a bit of a bugger. Does that not mean that they'll take a commission when it goes into my account and then out to the other accounts too?

Comment: No probs - but, unfortunately, yes. On the plus side, this can be mitigated by the fact that if all transactions are going through one account, you can apply for Merchant Rates which will decrease your costs.

Comment: Sorry, I should just add - This may not be the only way of doing it, it's just way I did quite a while ago. I'm not sure how the Paypal API has moved on since then.